# Can 1000w inverter with a peak power of 2000w be able to power a 160L refrigerator

Tags: inverter

Can 1000w inverter with a peak power of 2000w be able to power a 160L refrigerator,. ( Power ratting of the fridge is 130w/1.3a ).

Comment: 130W is less than 1000W

Comment: Not if the voltage isn't right.

Comment: 2000W is > 10x the appliance rated power so this will probably be OK.

Comment: @ Tom Carpenter,  motor starting currents are often ten times the run current,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the motor type used in the fridge, they can have a very high starting VA.

I saw a design several decades ago which was a battery power supply for a fridge. It used a 2-stage design. The first was a low power boost converter (a few hundred watts) to a 300 V DC bus, the second was a high current H-bridge which could handle the 1 kW VAr needed for the motor startup through its DC bus capacitors.

You maybe have enough power in reserve to do it in one device. Try it and see.